# Pandas pivot table with mean

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas data frame, df, that looks like this;

```
index  New  Old  MAP      Limit  count
1       93   35   54       > 18      1
2      163   93  116       > 18      1
3      134   78   96       > 18      1
4      117   81   93       > 18      1
5      194  108  136       > 18      1
6      125   57   79      <= 18      1
7       66   39   48       > 18      1
8      120   83   95       > 18      1
9      150   98  115       > 18      1
10     149   99  115       > 18      1
11     148   85  106       > 18      1
12      92   55   67      <= 18      1
13      64   24   37       > 18      1
14      84   53   63       > 18      1
15      99   70   79       > 18      1
```

I need to create a pivot table that looks like this

```
Limit   <=18   >18
New      xx1   xx2
Old      xx3   xx4
MAP      xx5   xx6
```

where values xx1, xx2, xx3, xx4, xx5, and xx6 are the mean of New, Old and Map for respective Limit.
How can I achieve this?
I tried the following without success.

```
table = df.pivot_table('count', index=['New', 'Old', 'MAP'], columns=['Limit'], aggfunc='mean')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Solution

```
df.groupby('Limit')['New', 'Old', 'MAP'].mean().T

Limit  <= 18        > 18
New    108.5  121.615385
Old     56.0   72.769231
MAP     73.0   88.692308
```

Comment: nice! i've completely forgotten about transposing